# Installation of Tandoor on shared webhoster (no root access)

Tags: python, django, shared-hosting

I'm trying to install Tandoor (https://tandoor.dev) on my uberspace (https://uberspace.de - shared webhoster). Docker is not supported by uberspace, so I tried the manual installation guide: https://docs.tandoor.dev/install/manual/

I run into several problems though. When running

```
/var/www/recipes/bin/pip3 install -r requirements.txt --user
```

I get the following message:

```
Could not find a tag or branch '7cab78c4531780ab4b32033d5104ccd5be1a246a', assuming commit.
Collecting Django==4.0.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==4.0.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.4.14, 1.4.15, 1.4.16, 1.4.17, 1.4.18, 1.4.19, 1.4.20, 1.4.21, 1.4.22, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11, 1.5.12, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.6.10, 1.6.11, 1.7, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7.10, 1.7.11, 1.8a1, 1.8b1, 1.8b2, 1.8rc1, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.8.8, 1.8.9, 1.8.10, 1.8.11, 1.8.12, 1.8.13, 1.8.14, 1.8.15, 1.8.16, 1.8.17, 1.8.18, 1.8.19, 1.9a1, 1.9b1, 1.9rc1, 1.9rc2, 1.9, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 1.9.6, 1.9.7, 1.9.8, 1.9.9, 1.9.10, 1.9.11, 1.9.12, 1.9.13, 1.10a1, 1.10b1, 1.10rc1, 1.10, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.10.7, 1.10.8, 1.11a1, 1.11b1, 1.11rc1, 1.11, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.11.4, 1.11.5, 1.11.6, 1.11.7, 1.11.8, 1.11.9, 1.11.10, 1.11.11, 1.11.12, 1.11.13, 1.11.14, 1.11.15, 1.11.16, 1.11.17, 1.11.18, 1.11.20, 1.11.21, 1.11.22, 1.11.23, 1.11.24, 1.11.25, 1.11.26, 1.11.27, 1.11.28, 1.11.29, 2.0a1, 2.0b1, 2.0rc1, 2.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9, 2.0.10, 2.0.12, 2.0.13, 2.1a1, 2.1b1, 2.1rc1, 2.1, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.7, 2.1.8, 2.1.9, 2.1.10, 2.1.11, 2.1.12, 2.1.13, 2.1.14, 2.1.15, 2.2a1, 2.2b1, 2.2rc1, 2.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.2.5, 2.2.6, 2.2.7, 2.2.8, 2.2.9, 2.2.10, 2.2.11, 2.2.12, 2.2.13, 2.2.14, 2.2.15, 2.2.16, 2.2.17, 2.2.18, 2.2.19, 2.2.20, 2.2.21, 2.2.22, 2.2.23, 2.2.24, 2.2.25, 2.2.26, 2.2.27, 2.2.28, 3.0a1, 3.0b1, 3.0rc1, 3.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.0.4, 3.0.5, 3.0.6, 3.0.7, 3.0.8, 3.0.9, 3.0.10, 3.0.11, 3.0.12, 3.0.13, 3.0.14, 3.1a1, 3.1b1, 3.1rc1, 3.1, 3.1.1, 3.1.2, 3.1.3, 3.1.4, 3.1.5, 3.1.6, 3.1.7, 3.1.8, 3.1.9, 3.1.10, 3.1.11, 3.1.12, 3.1.13, 3.1.14, 3.2a1, 3.2b1, 3.2rc1, 3.2, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.2.3, 3.2.4, 3.2.5, 3.2.6, 3.2.7, 3.2.8, 3.2.9, 3.2.10, 3.2.11, 3.2.12, 3.2.13, 3.2.14, 3.2.15)
No matching distribution found for Django==4.0.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 22.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Changing the Django version in the requirements file does not work either.

Can anyone help me and maybe guide me trough the installation? You can find the documentation on uberspace and it's features online: https://manual.uberspace.de

Answer (score 0):

Pip dependencies on uberspace seem to be bound to the specific python versions. You can however easily switch the python version according to [the documentation](https://manual.uberspace.de/lang-python/?highlight=python).

A working example could look as follows:

```
python3.9 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```